# Android app doesn't ask if you really want to delete a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, deleted-comments

App version: 1.0.31
Device: Nexus 7
Problem: On the app if I go to delete a comment, I don't get asked "Are you sure you want to delete the comment", the comment is just deleted. I miss clicked and pressed delete instead of going to my profile. On a browser you get asked: `Really delete this comment?`

Comment: Same behavior in iOS app. Need a confirmation first, +1.

Comment: +1 I have accidentally deleted my comments twice

Answer (score 6):

I definitely agree that this is required. It's way too easy to hit "Delete" when meaning to hit "Edit" or anything else.

I did consider doing a GMail style "Tap to undo", but there's no real way to undo a comment deletion using the API and I didn't want tapping delete to simply add the call to a queue and fake delete it until after the "Tap to undo" message goes away, when it would actually send the call to delete to the API, since that opens up a lot of different race conditions.

As of version 1.0.34, you'll see the following pop-up when attempting to delete a comment. I've also fixed a bad issue with the actual deletion happening on the UI thread (which is why the app was freezing for a second or two when deleting comments previously). Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hey you tried to delete my comment!! How rude. :-P

Comment: Hmm... looks like [there is no more such a dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248263/it-is-too-easy-to-delete-your-comment-in-android-app?noredirect=1#comment813275_248263)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not convinced this is necessary?

Currently on the app, it is a two step process, first to get the "comment options" (of which there are just 2) then tap "delete".

On the browser it is also a two step process, but there is a dedicated button for "delete", so the next step is the confirmation.

Adding a "confirmation" on the app would make it a three step process.

### Alternative suggestion

After the comment is deleted, have a floating "undo" button that stays visible for a second or two. Tapping "undo" naturally undoes the deletion. This is how the Gmail app works when deleting emails - there is no explicit "confirmation".

Comment: So what happens if you miss and accidentally hit "Delete" instead of "Edit"? And as for the alternate suggestion, that could get quite annoying when trying to delete multiple comments in succession, or trying to delete a comment quickly.