# No confirmation pop up when deleting comments (Android app)

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

According to [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230599/android-app-doesnt-ask-if-you-really-want-to-delete-a-comment), we should get a  confirmation pop up when trying to delete comments from within the android app.

However, I do not get such pop up when touching the delete button in the app.

Because of that, I have numerous times accidentally deleted my own comment (sometimes very long) when I wanted to simply edit it.

Can this please be fixed?

The app version for which this doesn't work for me is 1.0.56.
Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Really?! You get a nice big and clear dialog: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230599/android-app-doesnt-ask-if-you-really-want-to-delete-a-comment so really can't see how it can be too easy to delete. Unless of course you don't bother to read messages, and that's really your problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The dialog never appeared in my case. I just touched the recycle bin and the comment is suddenly gone.

Comment: Yep, the dialog never appears and it is enough to touch the delete button. Just tried it again.

Comment: So please change this question into a bug report, saying that you don't get the confirmation dialog and I'll reverse my downvote here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Try posting a comment saying 'Test comment. Test comment.' right in this post with your Android app and then touch your comment and touch the delete button. Does the dialog appear? I want to make sure this really is a bug by making sure we both get different results for the exact same actions. If you can't do it at the moment, I will wait. Thanks.

Comment: No android app for me, only iOS.

Comment: Eh thanks @Tim, I forgot to retag! *blush*

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this since the usage of action bar for comments. Probably a regression, but I was too lazy to post this bug report. On the other hand, please include the app version to clarify the issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. Edited the question.

Comment: Yes I agree this happens and should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next Android build.  It looks like the dialog was lost when the comment action dialog was removed.